# Binary search to get original index in an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, search, binary

I have an array “a” like the following:

```
let a = [1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 0.0, 5.0] // original array
```

I am looking to find the number 10.0 in “a” using binary search.

For that I sort the array to get array “asr”:

```
let asr = a.sorted()
print(asr)
// [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0]
```

Binary search for 10.0 in “asr” will return me index = 4. Whereas I am looking for index = 2 as in the original array “a”. And I am also looking for speed since my arrays are long.

Any suggestions?

I paste below the binary search algorithm I am using:

```
func binarySearch<T:Comparable>(inputArr:Array<T>, searchItem: T)->Int{
var lowerIndex = 0;
var upperIndex = inputArr.count - 1

 while (true) {
    let currentIndex = (lowerIndex + upperIndex)/2
    if(inputArr[currentIndex] == searchItem) {
        return currentIndex
    } else if (lowerIndex > upperIndex) {
        return -1
    } else {
        if (inputArr[currentIndex] > searchItem) {
            upperIndex = currentIndex - 1
        } else {
            lowerIndex = currentIndex + 1
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

I give example of my x (time) and y (value) arrays. For multiple such arrays, I need to find maximum of values in y and store the related unique x value.

```
let x = [230.0, 231.0, 232.0, 233.0, 234.0, 235.0, 236.0, 237.0, 238.0, 239.0, 240.0, 241.0, 242.0, 243.0, 244.0, 245.0, 246.0, 247.0, 248.0, 249.0, 250.0, 251.0, 252.0, 253.0, 254.0, 255.0, 256.0, 257.0, 258.0, 259.0, 260.0, 261.0, 262.0, 263.0, 264.0, 265.0, 266.0, 267.0, 268.0, 269.0, 270.0, 271.0, 272.0, 273.0, 274.0, 275.0, 276.0, 277.0, 278.0, 279.0, 280.0, 281.0, 282.0, 283.0, 284.0, 285.0, 286.0, 287.0, 288.0, 289.0, 290.0, 291.0, 292.0, 293.0, 294.0, 295.0, 296.0, 297.0, 298.0, 299.0, 300.0, 301.0, 302.0, 303.0, 304.0, 305.0, 306.0, 307.0, 308.0, 309.0, 310.0, 311.0, 312.0, 313.0, 314.0, 315.0, 316.0, 317.0, 318.0, 319.0, 320.0, 321.0, 322.0, 323.0, 324.0, 325.0, 326.0, 327.0, 328.0, 329.0, 330.0, 331.0, 332.0, 333.0, 334.0, 335.0, 336.0, 337.0, 338.0, 339.0, 340.0, 341.0, 342.0, 343.0, 344.0] // unique ascending time stamps

let y = [-0.0050202642876176198, 0.022393410398194001, 0.049790254951834603, 0.077149678828730195, 0.104451119608423, 0.131674058448602, 0.15879803550636501, 0.185802665315146, 0.21266765210574901, 0.239372805059962, 0.26589805348529699, 0.29222346189943499, 0.31832924501308402, 0.34419578259991401, 0.36980363424246498, 0.39513355394291599, 0.42016650458771598, 0.444883672255248, 0.46926648035572899, 0.49329660359275201, 0.51695598173596602, 0.54022683319452802, 0.56309166838114799, 0.58553330285668204, 0.60753487024536401, 0.62907983491101405, 0.65015200438466503, 0.67073554153427395, 0.690814976467372, 0.71037521815772098, 0.72940156578721904, 0.74787971979453605, 0.765795792622184, 0.783136319153938, 0.79988826683476, 0.816039045465632, 0.83157651666592303, 0.84648900299618601, 0.86076529673452795, 0.87439466829995904, 0.88736687431637595, 0.89967216531114802, 0.91130129304248497, 0.92224551745010597, 0.93249661322397404, 0.94204687598616199, 0.95088912808120296, 0.95901672397057403, 0.96642355522725798, 0.97310405512663301, 0.979053202830236, 0.98426652715924901, 0.98874010995489703, 0.99247058902319396, 0.99545516066186102, 0.99769158176748995, 0.99917817152138799, 0.99991381265282298, 0.99989795227872502, 0.99913060231921702, 0.99761233948865402, 0.99534430486218395, 0.99232820301815805, 0.98856630075702201, 0.98406142539766805, 0.97881696265251605, 0.97283685408292797, 0.96612559413686105, 0.95868822677099297, 0.95053034165985795, 0.94165806999482904, 0.93207807987612601, 0.92179757130129403, 0.91082427075393002, 0.89916642539671898, 0.88683279687313799, 0.87383265472251104, 0.86017576941332496, 0.84587240500008198, 0.83093331140918203, 0.81536971635963695, 0.79919331692469797, 0.78241627074072795, 0.76505118686993401, 0.74711111632382299, 0.72860954225449404, 0.70956036982116599, 0.68997791573951905, 0.66987689752174295, 0.649272422415344, 0.62817997604904996, 0.60661541079433601, 0.584594933851312, 0.56213509506794002, 0.53925277450172504, 0.51596516973324402, 0.49228978294099801, 0.46824440774739501, 0.44384711584564701, 0.41911624341769299, 0.39407037735334999, 0.36872834128103499, 0.34310918142055002, 0.31723215226859403, 0.291116702127733, 0.26478245848970899, 0.23824921328407, 0.21153690800324301, 0.18466561871516801, 0.157655540974798, 0.130526974645817, 0.10330030864392201, 0.07599600561323, 0.048634586547227202, 0.0212366153658834] // y values (could be repeating)
```

Comment: Well sorting the array has a time complexity of O(nlog(n)), so already you're just better off doing a linear search.

Comment: If you do *multiple* searches on a *large* array then you can create a sorted array of index/element pairs with  `a.enumerated().sorted(by: { $0.element < $1.element })`, then do a binary search on that to find the element together with the original index.

Answer (score 0):

Use another array which keeps the indexes. Like:

```
let indexArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then whenever you switch a number in your original array, switch the equivalent values in indexArray.

At the end the index array would be like:

```
[3, 0, 1, 4, 2]
```

using this you can easily get the original index. 
 If you send the code you are using to sort I can change the code and show you how to do it..

Another method:

You can keep a copy of your original array:

```
let copyArray = a.copy()
```

then use this to find the index of each value:

```
let indexOfA = copyArray.index(of: "aValue")
copyArray[indexOfA] = nil
// OR if the values are all positive
copyArray[indexOfA] = -1
```

Comment: Thanks Besat ! I edited my post to include the binary search code.

Comment: No worries. You need to do it when you are sorting the array, so I need the part of code you sort not the part you search in the sorted array

Comment: I just use "let asr = a.sorted()"

Comment: oh..OK. in that case you can keep a copy of your original array:

let copyArray = a.copy()

then use this to find the index of each value:

let indexOfA = copyArray.index(of: "aValue")

Comment: @Besat: That would work only if all array elements are unique.

Comment: If the array values are not unique, you can get the first index and then change the value for that index to nil or something which you are sure it does not exist in the array (for example -1 if all the values are positive)

Comment: Thanks to all!

@ GoZoner: Seems issues when array has repeated values. Then it picks (n-1)th index of repeated values. Generally, it should pick the first index of repeated values. Eg: for 4 in [2,3,4,4,4,0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 0] should be index 2 (your code: index 3). Same when 4 in [2,3,4,4,4,0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 0] should be 2 (your code:: index 6).

@ Martin R: Actually I have accompanying time index vectors with unique & increasing values. So if the enumerate can map those rather than indexes, it should work. Could you tell me how to map a different vector to the sorted y values?

Answer (score 0):

It is natural to express a binary search as a recursive algorithm - and usually clearer, at least when you are comfortable with recursion.  How about this:

```
func binarySearchHelper <T:Comparable> (array: Array<T>, item:T, lower:Int, upper:Int) -> Int? {
  guard lower <= upper else { return nil }

  let center = (lower + upper) / 2

  return array[center] == item
    ? center
    : ((lower == center     ? nil : binarySearchHelper (array: array, item: item, lower: lower,      upper: center)) ??
       (upper == center + 1 ? nil : binarySearchHelper (array: array, item: item, lower: center + 1, upper: upper)))
}

func binarySearch <T:Comparable> (array: Array<T>, item:T) -> Int? {
  return binarySearchHelper (array: array, item: item, lower: array.startIndex, upper: array.endIndex)
}
```